# I have made a bad server endpoint in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I have bad server endpoint in my ArangoDB. This is stopping the system from starting. It will start with `--no-server` but can't even connect the arangosh.

How can one limit the endpoint that at start if just give the endpoint from the command `arangod --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529` it still tries to load all the endpoint that has in the database and fails.

Comment: Are there any error messages on startup? Normally you should see an error message indicating *why* the server couldn't connect to an endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

When starting arangod, it will try to bind to the endpoint specified in command-line option `--server.endpoint`. If this option is not specified in the startup command, the option may be present a configuration file that is used on startup.

Additionally, the server will try to bind to all endpoints specified in a file named `ENDPOINTS` in the server's database directory. This file is optional.

If any endpoint (regardless if specified via the command-line, a configuration file or in the `ENDPOINTS` file) is specified multiple times, then the server will refuse to start. This is because it will try to bind to an endpoint that it has already bound to.

When binding to an endpoint fails for whatever reason, there should be a line like this in the server's error log:

```
2015-06-03T11:37:23Z [4165] FATAL failed to bind to endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529'. Please check whether another instance is already running or review your endpoints configuration.
```

I can only guess what the actual error reason is in your case, but there may be an `ENDPOINTS` file present containing an endpoint that is also specified on the command-line or in a config file. In this case you should see the above error message. Removing the `ENDPOINTS` file will help in this case.

By the way, `--no-server` intentionally disables the HTTP server in arangod, so you won't be able to connect to it with the ArangoShell or anything else.